# Operator[] shows me error 'unary *'

Tags: c++, operators, syntax-error

I'm creating my own class String in C++.
I stacked at this point:

```
class String{
    char* arr;
    int len;

    String& operator[](int);
}

String& String::operator[](int n) {
len = 1;
arr = new char[1];
arr = *arr[n];
}
```

The compiler shows me this:

> In member function ‘String& String::operator’: error: invalid
>   type argument of ‘unary *’

Where is the bug?
Thanks for help! :)

Comment: In member function ‘`String& String::operator[](int)`’: error: invalid type argument of unary ‘`*`’ (have ‘`char`’) http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b628d5e7dbc608b9d3c638d6dbe46907-f674c1a6d04c632b71a62362c0ccfc51

Comment: Do you have a book on C++ where you could actually study this stuff starting from the basics? This really makes no sense :(

Comment: what are you expecting `arr = *arr[n];` to do?

Comment: what exactly do you want to `operator[]` to do? This operator should return a reference to a `char`, no?

Comment: where is the semicolon at the end of class definition.

Comment: @AndyProwl Get accustomed to it - a lot of people asking questions on SO lack common sense.

Comment: You can't just throw random text vaguely resembling code at the compiler and expect it to do something useful.

Comment: You're missing a return statement as well. Say hello to UB when it does compile.

Comment: @H2CO3: Yeah, seems like a recurring pattern :(

Comment: wat is this i dont even

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it should be sth like this, ask again if it still cannot compile.

```
class String{
    char* arr;
    int len;

    char operator[](int);
};

char String::operator[](int n) {
    //if (n >= len) throw;
    //if (arr = NULL) throw;
    return arr[n];
}
```